# How to manage memory in scolling components?

Tags: cocoa-touch, memory-management, scroll

Are there known and proven ways to manage memory with scrolling components like tables or grids other than recycling cells as is used in Cocoa?  The sequence of calculations and datasource/delegation calls needed to make this way of laying out views works but also makes coordinating complex animations with the cells and a scroll view error prone as you have to pay careful attention to the sequence of calls as it reloads data, scrolls to an offset and other mechanisms of the layout that affect the target frame of your animations.  I am looking for a more declarative approach to providing content to the scroll view and having it figure out a smart way to manage it's memory as is done by a browser when you load the DOM with a long vertical layout of pictures.

Comment: You don't provide content to NSScrollView, it does not ask for it, all it does is scrolling its view. What data view are you using (NSTableView, NSOutlineView, MSMatrix etc)? How many cells does that data view use? What exactly is the problem with animations?

Comment: I am writing a custom layout on top of `TUIScrollView`, the `UIScrollView` like component in the Twitter open source lib.  I don't like the datasource/delegate style of providing content to the component because it can be difficult to debug Core Animation changes.  In a typical NSTableView like implementation, the table has multiple methods that do layout logic that are called at different times.  These can unexpectedly break an animation if not coded perfectly. I want a more declarative style so I can time all the animations togethers, such as animating a row out as I resize the others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it easier to create my own custom layout classes that only do layout on my views and not to impose an elaborate protocol such as NSTableViewDataSource and the like that makes animation difficult to program.  I like to know exactly where my views are at all times, the complete hierarchy of each view and I don't like to keep a model in sync with my views so I store data on the views themselves.  In my mind the objects on screen are the one and only objects I like to orchestrate as a programmer.  I want direct declarative control over them kind of like a game programer.  By subclassing a scroll view directly and following very simple layout rules outside of the normal `layoutSubviews` methods of Cocoa to avoid surprise layouts, I was able to control my animations better and do more complex and fluid animations.  Hope this inspires someone to do the same.